# Uninitialized constant error when get follower user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do a user follower page.
In the /user_followers/new?follower_id=igor_martins I'm getting this error:

uninitialized constant User::UserFollower

Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10

```
if params[:follower_id]
  @friend = User.where(profile_name: params[:follower_id]).first
  @user_follower = current_user.user_followers.new(follower: @friend)
else
  flash[:error] = "Friend required"
end
```

Parameters:

{"follower_id"=>"igor_martins"}

the line 7 that the error ocurs is this:

```
 @user_follower = current_user.user_followers.new(follower: @friend)
```

The user_followers.rb

```
class UserFollowers < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'follower_id'

end
```

the user.rb

```
has_many :user_followers
     has_many :followers, through: :user_followers
```

Why I'm getting this? I don't know why! I'm logged in!

Comment: do you have both relations set in the models? belongs_to, has_many ?

Comment: Do you have `UserFollower` class? How is the file containing this class named?

Comment: I'd guess a `UserFollower` is a `User`, if so, have you set `class_name: "User"` in your association?

Comment: HI! i've edited and posted the models assossiations

Comment: my class name `class UserFollowersController < ApplicationController`

Comment: @IgorMartins it's controller, not model. Did you learn any Rails basics?

Comment: Sorry. The model it's in the question...

Comment: current_user.followers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should be named `UserFollower` and the containing file should be named accordingly, `user_follower.rb`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add namespace to UserFollower class like this:

```
class User::UserFollowers < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

end
```

or module

```
module User
  class UserFollowers < ActiveRecord::Base

    ...

  end
end
```